# Xdebug end step debug session directly from source code

Tags: php, debugging, xdebug, xdebug-3

Due to some system limitations I have to manually start a Xdebug connection with `xdebug_connect_to_client();`. Later I want to end the step debugging session manually directly from the code so the IDE automatically also ends it.

I tried using `xdebug_disable()` followed by `xdebug_enable()` but this only disable the collection of some call stack.